# Batch mode SSH gives error "TERM environment variable not set"

Tags: linux, ssh

I made sure that TERM was defined in the .bashrc.

However, when running ssh in batch mode I get:

```
 $ ssh pc-lab7 "echo $TERM; echo $0"
    TERM environment variable not set.
    linux
    -bash
```

If I run ssh in interactive mode, I do not see this error.

How can I eliminate this error message?

Comment: Only interactive shells read `~/.bashrc`. Use `~/.bash_profile` (but bear in mind that defining `TERM` in either is probably a bad idea).

Comment: I tried to use ~/.bash_profile and export it there, but I still see the same error.
I even tried to set it in the /etc/profile and did not see any difference in the output.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, messed it up totally `~/.bash_profile` is only read by *login* shells. Non-interactive shells do not automatically execute any .rc files.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your answer.
Is there a way to set the TERM for the non interactive SSH. I am trying to install a software that tries to SSH in batch mode and it fails because the first line of output is "TERM environment variable not set"
I cannot modify the command it executes.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your system, TERM should normally be set, even if to 'dumb'. Perhaps it's not set on the local machine?

Comment: Note that $TERM and $0 are expanded before ssh invoked, due to absence of single quotes.

Answer (score 16):

Use `-t` option to ssh; it allocates tty.

```
 -t      Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary
         screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful,
         e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t options force tty
         allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

Comment: Just curious. Is this helpful with crontabs? I mean if it's tested. I know it's likely.

Answer (score 7):

I finally found the reason for this annoying "TERM environment variable not set" warning.

It turned out that when the ssh is executing in batch mode without an interactive user, a call to 'clear' command in a startup script will yield this error.

Commenting out the 'clear' line in the script fixed the issue for me.